# Why do you count the number of times a function gets called in unit test

Tags: unit-testing, testing

My new colleague incessantly insist me to count the number of times functions inside a unit test gets called when doing backend unit testing. I can see why it can be helpful at times but for most part I feel that it is redundant and unnecessary. From my perspective, it should not matter what function gets called and how many times it gets called. What matters is what goes in and comes out to check the expected behavior.

Unit testing should be more like a black box as in it doesnt matter how you get the answer, but matters if the answer is correct or not. If I am always validating the number of times some functions gets called, it creates a lot of overhead cost. It also means that everytime I change the approach to solve the problem, my unit test would break and I will need to fix it every single time. I feel like this approach limits the flexibility of coders.

Can anyone please tell me why these sort of unit testing should be performed? Thank you.

To be more specific, the code is in java and the overview of the structure is as follows: the controllers handles api calls and make calls to relevant facade, which in turn calls services to fetch the data. The facade is combination of services and the services talk to the database. These "unit tests" need to be performed for all three layers. Eg. checking the number of times each facade in the controllers gets called. And checking if each services inside the facade gets called and how many times it gets called.

Answer (score 2):

> Can anyone please tell me why these sort of unit testing should be performed?

Generally speaking, *it should not*. How many times a function is called is a private implementation detail. Unit testing tests public behavior of the unit, not it's private implementation.

As with every general statement there are exceptions: the number of times a method is called might be valuable in asserting whether the function of the component was correct. For example I once build a caching system, where you could put a cache in a pipeline and to check if it worked correctly, not only had the pipeline to deliver the correct result still, but the producer method should be called for input only *once*. If it was called multiple times, something was wrong with the implementation of the cache.

But as I said, that's a reasonable *exception*. Generally speaking, how many times a method is called is not a test criteria.

Answer (score 0):

Consider that you have the following method

```
public void ChargeCreditCard(string cardNumber, decimal amount)
```

It matters a lot if the credit card gets charded one or more times, right ?

I usually always test the number of times a method is called. First, it somehow guarantees that the method is not called more or less times by accident.
As for the statement that this kind of check adds additional overhead, this is not entirely true. If you're using good practices when designing your code and tests, it should be very easy to test such thing. Moreover, most mocking frameworks provides this kind of testing out of the box.

Comment: I would argue that the important part is that there is only a single charge to the card in the end... if that was achieved by calling the method 42 times, that's an implementation detail.

Comment: What means implementaion detail? You have this method called from some other class for which you're writing the unit tests. So, when writing the tests for that specific class, it's very importaint to test that this method is called exacly one (or whatever) times.

Comment: Again, is it? It is important to test, that only the amount to be charged actually *was* charged. How many times a function in code was called is irrelevant. If calling them multiple times charges the account multiple times, you already have that covered by checking the right amount was charged.

Comment: If we're talking about integration testing, yes, you're right. But I am under the impression that here it's about unit testing and for that reason when we test the caller of the ChargeCreditCard, we only test that the method is actually called x times. We don't even care what the method does at all.

Comment: Seems counter intuitive for me. I normally write tests that assert that a result is achieved (for example X amount of money is charged from a credit card). Asserting that other code is called implies detailed knowledge that the tester should not (need to) have. But I'm not a big fan of mocking everything that can be mocked just because either. I'd have an "InMemoryCreditCardAccount" that satisfies the `ICreditCardCharger`interface that is equired and I'd check if exactly one charge of X has been filed against it...

Comment: Technically, that might produce the same check, but I find it more intuitive to fail a test with "Credit card was not charged with X exactly once", instead of "ChargeCreditCard was called more than once". The former is a real test case anybody will understand, the later is technical detail.

Comment: That's exactly the point. You want to verify that the back account was actually charged with X amount. This is integration\QA testing. For unit-test, for me (as developer) is importaint to mock this method and verify that it was called 1 time. I don't care about back accounts in that context :)  In general I am not saying that you're wrong, we just have different thoughts about the problem. The the quesiton is a bit pjilosophical and there is more than one answer. Cheers!